# Max path with 2D array in java , arbitrary cell to start

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I wanted to print the maximum value you can accumulate while moving on the 2D array until you go off the 2D edges. 
**Note** the user either move to the right or to the button on the 2D array.
For example
[image: Sample Input and output]

so I write the code like the following

```
public static int find(int[][] A) {
    int[][] solution = new int[A.length][A.length];

    solution[0][0] = A[0][0];
    // fill the first row
    for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
        solution[0][i] = A[0][i] + solution[0][i - 1];
    }

    // fill the first column
    for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
        
        solution[i][0] = A[i][0] + solution[i - 1][0];
    }

    // path will be either from top or left, choose which ever is maximum
    int temp=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < A.length; j++) {
           // if ((A[i][j]+ Math.max(solution[i - 1][j], solution[i][j - 1])) >A[i][j] )
            solution[i][j] = A[i][j]
                    + Math.max(solution[i - 1][j], solution[i][j - 1]);
                //  else solution[i][j] = A[i][j];
                    
        }
    }
    int temp1 = 0;
    int temp2 =0;
    for(int i=0; i< A.length; i++){
       // System.out.println(" temp1= "+temp1);
        if(solution[i][A.length-1] > temp1) temp1= solution[i][A.length-1];
        //System.out.println(" temp1= "+temp1);
        if(solution[A.length-1][i] > temp2) temp2= solution[A.length-1][i];
       // System.out.println(" temp2= "+temp2);
    }
    for(int i=0; i< A.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j< A.length;j++){
            System.out.print(solution[i][j]+"\t");
        }
         System.out.println(" ");
    }
    return Math.max(temp1,temp2);
    
}
```

but it gives me 592 as an output and didn't know where is the problem in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem says that *maximum value you can accumulate while moving on the 2D array*, so the path of maximum sum can start from anywhere and end anywhere.
You should keep maximizing the result at each location `(i,j)`. The maximum at each location can be one of the three below:

- The value at the location itself : `A[i][j]`
- The value + the maximum so far when you come from top : `d[i-1][j] + A[i][j]`
- The value + the maximum so far when you come from left : `d[i][j-1] + A[i][j]`

You have to take the maximum of those three.

Code:

```
public static int find(int[][] A) {
     int R = A.length;
     int C = A[0].length;
     int[][] d = new int[R+1][C+1];
     int res = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     for ( int i = 1; i <= R; i++ ) {
       for ( int j = 1; j <= C; j++ ) {
          d[i][j] = Math.max( A[i-1][j-1], Math.max(d[i][j-1] + A[i-1][j-1], d[i-1][j] + A[i-1][j-1]));
          res = Math.max( res, d[i][j]);
       }
     }
     return res;
   }
```

Output : 603

You can play with this code [here](https://repl.it/repls/ScaredMustyLanserver)

Comment: Thank you very much!
how could I change it to recursion function please ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Seems like my code is just like yours...
Anyways, I got 547.
The max will be `solution[A.length-1][A.length-1]`.

---

Original Answer:
Here's what I got, using javascript (547) - I'm sure you can "translate" it to the language of your choice:

```js
var inputArray=[
  [-45,  87, -43, -12,   3, -39, -61, -19],
  [ 97, -64,  79, -75,  19,  97,  80,  12],
  [-24, -62,  46,  97, -75, -45,  92,  69],
  [ 87, -31,  74,  33, -49,   1,  27,  95],
  [ 13, -82, -19,  14, -76,  95,  64, -33],
  [-25,  45, -61,  90, -90,  43,  32,  96],
  [-27,  38,  77, -42,  36,  71,  32,  30],
  [ 27, -52, -66, -78, -42,  66,  69, -11]
];
console.log(JSON.stringify(inputArray));

var maxArray=[];
for(var i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++) {
  maxArray[i]=[];
  for(var j=0; j<inputArray.length; j++) {
    maxArray[i][j]=0;
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(maxArray));

maxArray[0][0]=inputArray[0][0];
for(var i=1; i<inputArray.length; i++) {
  maxArray[0][i]=maxArray[0][i-1]+inputArray[0][i];
  maxArray[i][0]=maxArray[i-1][0]+inputArray[i][0];
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(maxArray));

for(var i=1; i<inputArray.length; i++) {
  for(var j=1; j<inputArray.length; j++) {
    maxArray[i][j]=Math.max(maxArray[i-1][j], maxArray[i][j-1]) + inputArray[i][j];
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(maxArray));

var max=maxArray[inputArray.length-1][inputArray.length-1];
console.log("Max="+max);
```

I've used `console.table` instead of `console.log(JSON.stringify`, but snippet doesn't support it.
I've logged the results of each step.
First, I created an array of same dimension filled with zeros.
Then, I've copied first column/row's value.
Then, I've populated the rest of the first row and first column by adding `inputArray` and left/up values.
Then, I've populated the rest of the matrix by adding `inputArray` and max of left/up.
Last column holds max values should you go off to the right, and last row - off the bottom.
Furthest corner will be the absolute max - and I've logged it.